# Rafael JS does not appear to include space in text.getBBox().width

Tags: javascript, svg

I would like to get the width of Rafael engendered text, including the space from the space bar.  However, I find that

```
text=Canvas.paper.text(wordPos, linePos, word).attr({"font-size": fontSize,
                    "font-weight":TextParams.fontWeight, "fill":TextParams.color, "text-anchor":"start"});
console.log('text.getBBox().width (w/o space)='+text.getBBox().width);
word+=' ';
text=Canvas.paper.text(wordPos, linePos, word).attr({"font-size": fontSize,
                    "font-weight":TextParams.fontWeight, "fill":TextParams.color, "text-anchor":"start"});
console.log('text.getBBox().width (with space)='+text.getBBox().width);
```

returns

```
text.getBBox().width (w/o space)=51.125
text.getBBox().width (with space)=51.125
```

Is there a way to get the width of the text including the space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

empty spaces at the beginning or ends of strings get trimmed off in HTML text, I assume the same is happening with the SVG text that Raphael generates. You could try an HTML entity like `&nbsp;` instead of just a space bar space. Not sure if Raphael and SVG accept HTML entities

Comment: Unfortunately they don't.  It appears that I will need to add code to say where the spaces should be.  Thanks for your answer.